# Create nested object and insert in parent in one transaction

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

My mongodb collections are as follows-

--users--

```
{   
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7d123d6efd87624ca5b8a8"), 
    "todos" : [ 
        ObjectId("5d7d25e14fb313536060fbac"), 
        ObjectId("5d7d267c4fb313536060fbad")
    ],
    "name" : "user1",
    "email" : "user1@email.com",
}
```

--todos--

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7d25e14fb313536060fbac"), 
    "summary" : "first todo",
    "user" : ObjectId("5d7d123d6efd87624ca5b8a8"),
}
```

My query is that I want to add new Todos under the user object while creating the same in todos collection and adding its reference in user's object... all in one transaction.

What I have done currently is -
1. Create a new Todo object (db transaction #1)
2. Find the user with user id (db transaction #2)
3. Update the user's todos array (db transaction #3)

I want to do all these on just one transaction.
Any help?

Comment: Hi Sunny, have you considered merging both schemas (user and todos)? Is the separation necessitated by an objective?

Comment: Hi @Grey, I am learning Nodejs + Mongodb + Mongoose stack. And I want to solve this problem so that I can understand some real world scenarios.. 
In real world, there are many times documents can be embedded, however many other times they cant be .. In such cases, how do we execute the transactions among the documents in single shot ?

Comment: Hello Sunny, Take a read at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/ for addressing concerns regarding using transactions in MongoDB. Also, you can use a two phase commit to handle the situation (see https://codeburst.io/fawn-transactions-in-mongodb-988d8646e564). I hope you find these pointers helpful.